# pyQt5 - error converting value taken from QTableView

Tags: pyqt5

I would need to populate fields of a form based on the values taken from a selected row in a QTableView displayed on another form. The code works fine for text fields but I'm having problem when I have to set the value of a double spinbox: below is the statement which throw an exception.
The field dSB_costi has been defined on the form with a double spinbox widget. The issue is the field 'self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 4)' taken from the selected row of the QTableView present in the first form (form1) is passed as string.
Additionally the fields taken from the QTableView contains 42,00 as I need use comma as decimal separator.
I tried to use float() to convert the value before the setValue statement but I get the error 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '42,00'
Thanks for any guidance you might provide

```
    self.w.dSB_costi.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 4)))
```

Comment: That depends on the reason for which the value is actually "42,00": how was that value set? Does the database have proper type hints for columns (specifically, `REAL` for column 4)? The conversion error you're getting is because the model has a *string* value that uses the comma as decimal separator, while `float()` only works with the dot, but the point is still that that column should *not* use nor accept string values.

Comment: The value was set importing a .csv file in a SQLite db tables. The field in the table has been defined as DOUBLE.

Comment: `DOUBLE` should result in a `REAL`, which should properly provide a QDoubleSpinBox editor, so it should *not* be a string. But that depends on how the data has been actually parsed and inserted, as SQLite uses dynamic typing and you could actually store a string in a numeric field. If you try to edit that field and you get a line edit instead of a spin box, it means that the source data uses the wrong type so you must decide if you should eventually check the csv import and ensure that types are correct (and eventually converted) or eventually override the `data()` of the model for that.

Comment: I checked the csv import and there uncorrect field types. Now, this part works. Thanks for the susggestion