# pyQt5 - Type error filling QDoubleSpinBox with data from QSQLTable model

Tags: pyqt5

I have the following problem using QDoubleSpinBox widget:

I have a program that select data from a SQLite table using the QSQLTable model and load them to a form using a QTableView (see below)
[image]

Selecting one row of the QTable view and pressing a QPushButton present in the form, the program displays a new form (see second image below) in which the widgets text/values of such new form should be filled based on the values taken from the selected row of the first form

[image]

The field 'Costi' is a QDoubleSpinBox (dSB_costi) and when I try to set its value taking data from the QSQLTable model (statement below) I get the error: *TypeError: setValue(self, float): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'*

self.w.dSB_costi.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 4)))

The field 'costi' in the SQLite table is defined as type 'REAL'

I put also the python code
Thanks for any help

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView,QWidget,QMessageBox,QMainWindow,                                 QDialog

from connect_SQLITE import Database
from tabelleGenericoUi import Ui_f_tabella
from insRisorseInterneUi import Ui_InsRisorseInterne


class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_f_tabella):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.w = None # No external window yet.
        self.setWindowTitle("Gestione Risorse Interne")
        self.pb_Ins.setText("Inserimento Nuova Risorsa Interna")
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)       
        self.model.setTable("tb_RisorseInterne")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        widgets=("CDL", "Desc_CDL", "Tipo", "Desc_2", "Costi", "Troncone",             "BarraUtile", \
                 "SovrametalloPerTaglio", "CambioUtensile", "TempoCSAutomatico", \
                 "TempoRiposizCreSecPass", "TempoRiposizCreCaricMANUALE", "NrGiriMax-RPM")
        for field in widgets:
          self.model.setHeaderData(widgets.index(field), Qt.Horizontal,                                  widgets[widgets.index(field)])
        
        self.model.select()
        self.tView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
        self.tView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        
        self.pb_Ins.clicked.connect(self.inserimento_ri)
        self.model.submitAll()
        self.model.select()
      
    def inserimento_ri(self):
      if self.w is None:
         self.w = InserimentoRisorsaInterna()
         self.verifica_selezione_riga_tabella()  
         self.w.show()
         self.w.pb_conf.clicked.connect(self.conferma_inserimento_risorsa_interna)
      else:
         self.w.close()
         self.w = None # Discard reference, close window.
    
    def conferma_inserimento_risorsa_interna(self):
       """Aggiunta nuova risorsa"""   

       self.data = []
       for field in (self.w.lE_cdl, self.w.lE_descCDL, self.w.lE_tipo, self.w.lE_desc2, self.w.dSB_costi, \
                     self.w.sB_troncone, self.w.sB_barra_utile, self.w.sB_sovrametallo, \
                     self.w.dSB_cambio_utensile, self.w.sB_tempo_carico_auto, \
                     self.w.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass, self.w.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man, \
                     self.w.sB_nr_giri_max):    
            
            if not field.text():
                QMessageBox.critical(
                    self,
                    "Errore!",
                    f"Inserimento non consentito per mancanza di informazioni"   
                    #f"Inserire il valore {field.objectName()}",
                )
                self.data = None  # Reset .data
                return

            self.data.append(field.text())

       if not self.data:
            return
   
       rec = self.model.record()
       rows = self.model.rowCount()
  
       for column_index, field in enumerate(self.data): 
          rec.setValue(rec.fieldName(column_index), field)     
      
       self.model.insertRecord(-1, rec)
       self.model.submitAll()
       self.model.select()

    def verifica_selezione_riga_tabella(self): 
     for index in sorted(self.tView.selectionModel().selectedRows()):
      row = index.row()
      self.w.lE_cdl.setText(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 0)))
      self.w.lE_descCDL.setText(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 1)))
      self.w.lE_tipo.setText(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 2)))
      self.w.lE_desc2.setText(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 3)))
      self.w.dSB_costi.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 4))
      self.w.sB_troncone.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 5))
      self.w.sB_barra_utile.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 6))      
      self.w.sB_sovrametallo.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 7)   
      self.w.dSB_cambio_utensile.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 8))
      self.w.sB_tempo_carico_auto.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 9))    
      self.w.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_2pass.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 10))                                                                                                                                                                              self.w.dSB_tempo_rip_cre_car_man.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 11))
      self.w.sB_nr_giri_max.setValue(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 12)))
     

class InserimentoRisorsaInterna(QDialog,Ui_InsRisorseInterne):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.setupUi(self)

    
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())enter code here
```

Comment: The problem seems the same as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71407946/2001654), since the data stored in the database for that record is a string, not numeric: an integer (or float) `1` is *not* stored in the same way as the string `"1"`. You should convert the value from its string form, eventually checking the various decimal representation, but it would be better to properly fix the database or its creation.

Comment: In the SQLite db the field is defined as REAL so I think it's the correct type for this data. As far as I understood SQLite does not have 'static' data type and therefore it does not restrict the input to match the data type (e.g. if you enter the value 'aaa' in a REAL field it's accepted). As data in that db table have been imported from a .csv file, the 'costi' field can contain value like 27,52 that is intended as number (by a user perspective) while is stored as string

Comment: Then, as already said, you either ensure that the field *is* stored as number when importing the csv, or you "fix" the value when reading data from the database.

Comment: Could you provide an example about how could I "fix" the value read from db ? Thanks

Comment: I already told you: you either try to convert the string to a numeric value (by properly parsing the input and considering decimal separators) when trying to set the value to the spinbox, or you do the same by subclassing the model and overriding its `data()` function for the `Qt.DisplayRole`. But I'd *strongly* try to fix that from the source data, at least the model will *always* have valid and already sanitized data. In both cases, it depends on the source data, especially if it also has thousands separators, but you can easily do it by properly using `str.replace()`.